# Is there any way to make the js animation go backwards

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, jquery-animate

So I've been working on an animation and I cant figure out how to make the animation go backwards. I want it to got down to up, not up to down because obviously rocket ships launch and go up, not launch and go down

```js
var id = null;
function myMove() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("myAnimation");   
  var pos = 0;
  clearInterval(id);
  id = setInterval(frame, 10);
  function frame() {
    if (pos == 350) {
      clearInterval(id);
    } else {
      pos++; 
      elem.style.bottom = pos + 'px'; 
      elem.style.top = pos + 'px'; 
    }
  }
}
```

```css
<style>
#myContainer {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
  background: none;
}
#myAnimation {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
}
</style>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>
<button onclick="myMove()">Click Me</button> 
</p>

<div id ="myContainer">
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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" id="myAnimation" alt="rocket" />
</div>
```

so ya can anyone help me please

Comment: Don’t update `bottom` and `top` at the same time. Try updating _only_ `top`. Also, have you tried swapping the `350` and `0` values and use `pos--` instead of `pos++`?

Comment: i have tried swapping 350 and 0 and using pos-- instead of pos++. it didnt work. i also tried updading only top. it doesn't work. but updating only bottom works. thanks! but also the rocket teleports to the bottom and then moves so i will have to fix that

Comment: [What Do You Mean “It Doesn’t Work”?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/147616/289905) Making these four changes (remove `elem.style.bottom = pos + 'px';`; replace `0` by `350`; replace `350` by `0`; `pos--;`) makes the rocket go up. Maybe the initial position doesn’t match, but you can simply set it in CSS.

Comment: I think GSAP can do that

Comment: i will try what you said @SebastianSimon

Comment: hmm @SebastianSimon youre right